# How to compare this two hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm writing test case to compare two Hash.
There class name is same i.e hash.

```
{"first_name" => "Vikas", "last_name" => "Prasad" } == {first_name: "Vikas", last_name: "Prasad" }
```

This could be done by modifying the keys from any of the hash to_sym.

But I'm sure there's a different way of comparing this.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're comparing two hashes and you get correct result `false`, because these are two different hashes. What is the problem then?

Comment: No, you get the result `true`, because they have equivalent content.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice colons and assumed hashrockets. Then yes, you get `true`, because these hashes are indeed equal. Still, what's the problem?

Comment: All the keys are already symbols in both those hashes.

Comment: Do you mean `"first_name" => "Vikas"`, i.e. `=>` instead of `:`?

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question.

Comment: @MarekLipka you will get false. Try on console.

Comment: @Stefan yes it is.

Comment: @vikas95prasad like I wrote in the first place. After your edition, these are two different hashes, so no wonder you get `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Symbolize keys**

These hashes are not equal because the keys are not equal. If you want to compare the values, no matter whether the keys are strings or symbols you can just transform the keys using `to_sym`. (Note that this will not transform nested keys).

```
first_hash.transform_keys(&:to_sym) == second_hash.transform_keys(&:to_sym)
```

**2. Compare as JSON (NOT RECOMMENDED)**

I do not recommend this, but since it is technically possible, I included it here for fun and informational purposes.

Another way you can do this is to check whether the JSON representation is the same. It is probably slower, and requires the keys to be in the same order in each hash.

```
require 'json'
first_hash.to_json == second_hash.to_json
```

Comment: JSON option is useless, you'll have just two strings, the same as `{ foo: '1'}.to_s == {foo: '2'}.to_s`.

Comment: Yes, you end up with two strings which you can compare. I'm definitely not recommending to do this. But since `string` and `symbol` keys are represented the same in JSON, you can abuse it to compare hashes like this. (And no, `to_json` is not the same as `to_s`)

Comment: I dont say `to_json` is the same as `to_s`, I say an the end you're comparing two strings, it's useless.

Comment: Yes, you are comparing two strings. That is the whole point. If the two strings are equal, the hashes are probably also equal.

Comment: Also the it will fail if some key is an object for example.

Comment: @Зелёный: depends on how you define "fail": `{5 => 6}.to_json # => '{"5": 6}'`

Comment: How about object? `{ Object.new => '1'}.to_json`

Comment: I know that it will fail in some cases, and that it is definitely not best practice. That is why I also do not recommend it in UPPERCASE BOLD. But OP asked for different methods of comparing the hashes he supplied. And in that very specific case, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Sort-agnostic comparison:

```
h1, h2 = {"first_name" => "Vikas", "last_name" => "Prasad" },
         {first_name: "Vikas", last_name: "Prasad"} 

[h1, h2].
  map(&:sort).
  reduce(&:zip).
  flat_map do |(k1, v1), (k2, v2)|
    [k1.to_s == k2.to_s] && [v1 == v2]
  end.reduce(&:&)
```